# Regex Replace everything except between the first " and the last "

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

i need a regex that replaces everything except the content between the first " and the last ".

I need it like this:

Input String:`["Key:"Value""]`

And after the regex i only need this:

Output String:`Key:"Value"`

Thanks!

Comment: in your question you say "bracket", in the title you say "double quotes", and in the example your replacing both the brackets and the double quotes. Which is it?

Comment: @doom87er i mean double quote sorry for the confusing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

patern:
`^.*?"(.*)".*$`

Substion:
`$1`

[On Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DNaryg/1)

Explination:

the first part `^.*?"` matches as few characters as possible that are between the start of the string and a double quote

the second part`(.*)"` makes the largest match it can that ends in a double quote, and stuffs it all in a capture group

the last part `.*$` grabs what ever is left and includes it in the match

Finally you replace the entire match with the contents of the first capture group

Comment: Very good regexp! The `.` does not match newlines, but the original question didn't specify whether that's relevant. If it is, you can use `[^]` instead to match any character. Dart's replace does not have `"$1"` as a replacement pattern. You can do `input.replaceFirstMapped(re, (m) => m[1])` to replace with the first group.

Comment: i'm un-familiar with dart. but, if it has Regex options like most other Regex engines then you can use 's' (single-line) to allow `.` to match new-lines

Comment: Sadly (depending on perspective) Dart uses JavaScript's regular expressions. Even in multi-line mode, `.` still doesn't match line terminators.

Comment: `[^]` is not a regex to match nothing.  It's the beginning of a character class that won't match a right bracket, but it's a syntax error (incomplete character class)... you still need another right bracket, as in `[^]]`. A regex to match nothing would be something like `(?!)`.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz the goal isn't to match nothing, it's to match any character including new-line. `[^...]` is a negated character class, it matches anything not present in the set. leaving the set empty allows it to match any character. I don't know what you mean by "match nothing" but a negative look ahead without a pattern would prevent your regex from matching anything

Comment: OK, to match any character including newlines, I frequently use `[\d\D]`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you say why you need a *RegExp*?
A function like:

```
String unquote(String input) {
  int start = input.indexOf('"');
  if (start < 0) return input; // or throw.
  int end = input.lastIndexOf('"');
  if (start == end) return input; // or throw
  return input.substring(start + 1, end);
}
```

is going to be faster and easier to understand than a RegExp.

Anyway, for the challenge, let's say we do want a RegExp that replaces the part up to the first `"` and from the last `"` with nothing. That's two replaces, so you can do an

```
input.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$'), "")`
```

or you can use a capturing group and a computed replacement like:

```
input.replaceFirstMapped(RegExp(r'^[^"]*"([^]*)"[^"]*$'), (m) => m[1])
```

Alternatively, you can use the capturing group to *select* the text between the two and extract it in code, instead of doing string replacement:

```
String unquote(String input) {
  var re = RegExp(r'^[^"]*"([^]*)"[^"]$');
  var match = re.firstMatch(input);  
  if (match == null) return input; // or throw.
  return match[1];
}
```